# How decode a base64 string into gif file in sd card esp32 arduino IDE

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I convert the GIF file to  base64 string and it send over bluetooth serial terminal the esp32 receive it with serialBT.read and it be decode into a gif file.  I've been searching the internet for an hour and I've only found vague information on how to decode a sentence or how to do it on a PC. I was able to make a successful connection through BT serial but I have not had any idea how to decode the base64 string into a file, I have seen that it is decoded and a byte is created and then that byte is written to a .gif file in the sd card memory . Where can I start to be able to achieve that, could you give me some example? The code I used to communicate via BT.  The GIF file size not exceed the 30 KB, but some have only 10 KB? and resolution of 64x64 px.

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

I just started this so I don't have much idea of ​​starting to achieve what I want.

Chat gpt tell me the code

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <FS.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <base64.h>

void setup() {
  // Initialize SD card
  if (!SD.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  }
  uint8_t *buffer;
  size_t bufferSize;
  String base64String = "..."; // Your Base64 string here

  // Calculate the size of the buffer needed to hold the decoded bytes
  bufferSize = base64_dec_len(base64String.c_str(), base64String.length());

  // Allocate the buffer
  buffer = new uint8_t[bufferSize];

  // Decode the base64 string into the buffer
  base64_decode((char *)buffer, base64String.c_str(), base64String.length());

  // Open file for writing
  File file = SD.open("/output.bin", FILE_WRITE);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for writing");
    return;
  }

  // Write buffer to file
  file.write(buffer, bufferSize);

  // Close the file
  file.close();

  // Free the buffer
  delete[] buffer;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```